# Datastax Ring nodes showing wrongly

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup, datastax-enterprise-graph

We have 3 nodes in our existing Datastax cluster. Sometime the ring status showing wrongly, after dse service restart on wrong nodes the issue got solved.

**Correct :**

```
nodetool status
Datacenter: SearchGraph
=======================
UN  10.10.1.56  1015.41 MiB  1 ?  936a1ac0-6d5e-4a94-8953-d5b5a2016b92  rack1
UN  10.10.1.46  961.43 MiB  1 ?   3f41dc2a-2672-47a1-90b5-a7c2bf17fb50  rack1
UN  10.10.1.36  1013.72 MiB  1 ?  0822145f-4225-4ad3-b2be-c995cc230830  rack1
```

**Wrong :**

```
Datacenter: DC1
===============
?N  10.10.1.46  ?  1     ?       null           r1
?N  10.10.1.36  ?  1     ?       null           r1

Datacenter: SearchGraph
=======================
UN  10.10.1.56  1005.33 MiB  1 ?  null         rack1
```

Configuration Details is same on all nodes :

```
cat /etc/dse/cassandra/cassandra.yaml | grep endpoint_snitch:
endpoint_snitch: GossipingPropertyFileSnitch



cat /etc/dse/cassandra/cassandra-rackdc.properties |grep -E 'dc=|rack='
dc=SearchGraph
rack=rack1
```

Comment: Was there anything in the system.log on the node that the nodetool command was run on?

Comment: @mando222 I had only find same error in system.log ,no unusual log find in it.Thanks

Comment: Was the nodetool command run right after startup/bootstrap the first time?

Comment: Looks like something went amiss with gossip. Best thing to check is grabbing `nodetool gossipinfo` and `nodetool describecluster` from _each_ node when it happens again and also post the log files somewhere where they can be shared easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue got Resolved after restarting DSE nodes with saved_caches and hints folder content removed. I had tried to change the DC name in cassandra-rackdc.properties and revert it back earlier, may be issue caused by these.Thanks